# problem with break while using it to break nested loops in php

Tags: php, arrays, break

When I execute this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example_table");

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < $c; $j++)
    {
        if ($db_array[$j]['ID'] == $row['id'])
        {
            $del_counter = 0;
            break 2;
        }
        else
        $del_counter = 1;
    }

    if ($del_counter == 1)
    {
    $del_array[$i] = $row['id'];
    $i++;
    }

}
```

This does not break the two level looping. Instead, the $del_array stores all the row ids. I need to compare db_array[][id] with the array "row" (fetched from the database). And need to check which elements of db_array are deleted from the database. So, what I did is I tried to store the ids of deleted items in an array. But the break does not work. Am I missing something?

Thanks in anticipation.

BG

Comment: try to define $del_counter=0 just before the nested for.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but `break 2` will work as announced, so I would assume you have a logic flaw in your code. Use a step-debugger to see what's your code is doing.

Comment: Could you rephrase that a bit? If a row was deleted, how do you expect to retrieve it?

Comment: Isn't that you are always in the `else`?

Comment: If you say $del_array contains the whole result, then it means that the condition if ($db_array[$j]['ID'] == $row['id']) is not properly defined as it never sets to true.

Comment: don't know if it's elsewhere in your code but I don't see `$c` defined anywhere. Also, I have never seen `break` followed by a number either so I'm a bit confused :S

Comment: Hi People... Thank you for the valuable input. It was an error in my logic. I apologize for that :) Thanks again for your concern.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PHP manual:

```
1) break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure
2) break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it 
how many (the above mentioned) nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of
```

Your break is at the level 2, and hence `break 2;` should work as expected, so the problem is elsewhere. Is the `break 2` executed at all?

In any case, I would recommend a more robust solution, e.g.

```
$ok = True;
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && $ok) {
      ...
      if (...) $ok = False;  // anywhere deep
      ...
      if ($ok) {...}
}
```

Comment: break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure, so break 2 would work as expected

Comment: Thank you Jiri and matino. However, break 1 worked for me. It was a logic error from my side that I could not figure out at that moment.